# It is possible to access the DOM of a VoiceXML document? How?

Tags: javascript, dom, voicexml

With the  tag "data" I can only access static data. Instead I would like to write something like:

"getElementsByTagName('field').item(0).nodeValue"

in order to retrieve the value of the field just after that has been inserted.

(I know that there are other ways to obtain the same effect but I am interested in this specific topic).

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use DOM to retrieve items fetched using the <data> element - is that what you're trying to do? I'm not sure quite what part of the DOM you're trying to access - is there a formatting problem at the start of your question? I don't think there's normally a way to access the VoiceXML document itself with DOM (and no particular need to).

Comment: Yes, I would like to access the VoiceXML document itself with DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It is not normally possible to access the DOM of the VoiceXML document itself. (I can't think of any circumstances where this is necessary.)

Comment: Thanks Matthew! 

When you say: "not NORMALLY possible" you means that there are some special cases in which it could be possible?

Comment: I just mean that it's not completely impossible that someone might implement a voice browser with this functionality, but it's not required as part of the standard, as gawi says, so it's unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such mechanism in the the W3C VoiceXML 2.0/2.1 specification. VoiceXML is not as dynamic as HTML is.

Comment: Thanks gawi, 

It seems that DOM mechanism will be available in the next 3.0 version of the language.

[w3c: DOM Processing](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml30/#d3e591)